# Spring MVC : Ambiguous mapping found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I couldn't understand why the following gives an ambiguous mapping.

a. The controller class

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employees")
public class EmployeeController {

@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String get(Model model) {
    return "xx";
}

}
```

**Console output:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping found. Cannot map 'org.tutorial.spring.controller.EmployeeController#0' bean method 
public java.lang.String org.tutorial.spring.controller.EmployeeController.get(org.springframework.ui.Model)
to {[/employees/new],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}: There is already 'employeeController' bean method
public java.lang.String org.tutorial.spring.controller.EmployeeController.get(org.springframework.ui.Model) mapped.
```

It says method has already been mapped.
How so?

b. web.xml

```
<servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

c. spring.xml

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.tutorial.spring" />
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.tutorial.spring.controller.EmployeeController" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try removing the bean element

```
<bean class="org.tutorial.spring.controller.EmployeeController" />
```

from your XML. I suspect this is causing you problems because

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.tutorial.spring" />
```

will scan your package, and identify EmployeeController as a bean, due to its annotations. Then, afterwards, you are manually adding the same bean.